# SQL -What is the best way to search for a specific range in a column with numbers and letters?

Tags: mysql, r, sqldf

I have a table with codes with letters and numbers, specifically aa00 to ZZ99. I am having trouble figuring out the best way to search this column for a range such as dd01 - GG99. What would be the best way to do that? ( I am using sqldf with RStudio)

I have tried using a between statement such as but the results are not what I am looking for. In fact it is showing the opposite and no lower case letters:

```
SELECT prodcode
  FROM data
 WHERE prodcat BETWEEN 'GG99' AND 'dd01';
```

Edit too long for comments:

```
library(ggvis)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(sqldf)
library(tidyr)
data <- read_csv("C:/Users/name/Documents/test1.csv")
compn <-read_csv("C:/Users/name/Documents/test2.csv")


prodcode <- expand.grid(x1 = LETTERS,
                        x2 = letters,
                        x3 = 0:9,
                        x4 = 0:9)
prodcode$prodcat <- apply(data, 1, paste0, collapse = "")




test <- sqldf("SELECT prod
               FROM data, compn
               WHERE data.cono = compn.cono
               AND (SELECT * FROM prodcode 
                        WHERE (SUBSTR(UPPER(prodcat), 1, 2) >= 'DD' AND 
                        CAST(SUBSTR(prodcat, 3, 2) AS INT) >= 00 ) AND
                        (SUBSTR(UPPER(prodcat), 1, 2) <= 'GG' AND
                        CAST(SUBSTR(prodcat, 3, 2) AS INT) <= 99);
              GROUP BY prod
              ORDER BY prod ASC;")


test
```

Comment: Consider storing the string component separately from the numeric component.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction please. I have read that elsewhere but I have no idea how to get started.

Comment: Try the new release of dplyr, it has all the (fantastic) data wrangling tools now easy to use with databases. So you can just`filter` or `select` in the usual way. https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr

Comment: I assumed the data is in the proper format. How would I change AA00 to a string component using dplyr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the SQL code that will get what you propose.  In SQL, you need to break the letters and numbers apart to compare them.  Since your numbers have fixed width, you can get away with not converting to an `INT`.  If you have non-fixed width numeric values, you will have to decide what the appropriate sorting behavior is.

```
prodcode <- expand.grid(x1 = LETTERS,
                        x2 = letters,
                        x3 = 0:9,
                        x4 = 0:9)
prodcode$prodcat <- apply(prodcode, 1, paste0, collapse = "")

library(sqldf)

sqldf(
  "SELECT * FROM prodcode 
   WHERE (SUBSTR(UPPER(prodcat), 1, 2) >= 'DD' AND 
            CAST(SUBSTR(prodcat, 3, 2) AS INT) >= 00 ) AND
         (SUBSTR(UPPER(prodcat), 1, 2) <= 'GG' AND
            CAST(SUBSTR(prodcat, 3, 2) AS INT) <= 99)"
)
```

### Use in a subquery

```
proddata <- data.frame(prodcode = c("DD15", "BB08", "FQ17", "NN11"),
                       value = rnorm(4, 100, 15))

prodcode <- expand.grid(x1 = LETTERS,
                        x2 = letters,
                        x3 = 0:9,
                        x4 = 0:9)
prodcode$prodcat <- apply(prodcode, 1, paste0, collapse = "")

library(sqldf)

sqldf(
  "SELECT * 
   FROM proddata
   WHERE prodcode IN (SELECT UPPER(prodcat) FROM prodcode 
                      WHERE (SUBSTR(UPPER(prodcat), 1, 2) >= 'DD' AND 
                      CAST(SUBSTR(prodcat, 3, 2) AS INT) >= 00 ) AND
                      (SUBSTR(UPPER(prodcat), 1, 2) <= 'GG' AND
                      CAST(SUBSTR(prodcat, 3, 2) AS INT) <= 99))"
)
```

Comment: Can I add this like a subquery within the main query. Like this?
edited into main post.

Comment: As far as I am aware, yes.  I've never tried it myself, but `sqldf` supports the majority of the common functionality most SQL engines offer.

Comment: Edited my code in the main post. It is still not splitting the data up.

Comment: The prod code table is split but the data in it isnt split correctly as well.

Comment: Your edited query is incomplete.  You have a valid subquery following the `AND` but you aren't setting it equal to anything.  Should that perhaps be `AND some_variable IN (SELECT prodcat FROM ....)`?  That's what comes to mind at first glance.  Without a reproducible example, it will be hard to pinpoint exactly what the issue is.

Comment: the prodcode split isnt splitting the data up. it is just creating a table of possible values with the combinations of aa00 to ZZ99. I dont know what the 2nd line does and I thought from the SQL query I am just accessing the newly created table. Yet when I run it, it still runs and all the code is showing is product codes including CXXX

Comment: Just added a working example demonstrating use in a subquery.

Comment: Might consider using `x between y and z` construct.

Comment: @ggrothendieck that might be the third time in recent memory someone has made such a suggestion to me. Keep on me and eventually I'll catch on. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might think about `grepl` and a proper accompanying regex formula, paired into a dplyr select command.   It's hard to help you at the moment without being able to see what your "test" data frame actually consists of. (IE, no reproducible example available)